# getSerial() method on Marshmallow

Tags: java, android, serial-number

I'm new with Java and android and i need to basically retrieve hardware serial number from my device.
I've tried the following:

```
import android.content.*; 
import android.os.Build;
public static String recup_android()
{
String androidid;
String SerialNumber;
androidid=android.os.Build.MODEL;
SerialNumber=android.os.Build.getserial;
return SerialNumber;
}
```

I'm facing the following error:
java:40: error: cannot find symbol

```
    SerialNumber=android.os.Build.getserial;
                                 ^
```

symbol:   variable getserial
  location: class Build
1 error
:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

What am i missing there?
If I return androidid (MODEL) it then works OK.
Maybe something to have with the class declaration??

Thanks in advance for your precious help
Elie

Answer (score 10):

You are using getSerial incorrectly. Its a method not variable and available from API 26 or higher. For older versions, use `Build.SERIAL`

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) 
{
    // Todo Don't forget to ask the permission
    SerialNumber = Build.getSerial();
}
else
{
    SerialNumber = Build.SERIAL;    
}
```

Make sure you have **READ_PHONE_STATE** permission before calling `getSerial()`. Otherwise your app will crash.

Check [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) for asking permissions.

Comment: The method name should be `getSerial`

Comment: thanks so much for your quick reply. Should I then add a new getserial() and then use .tostring to send it to a string?

Comment: @SoundOfThunder getSerial() return type is String. No need to use toString(). Check my updated answer. And don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem ;)

Comment: OK. I'm really sorry but i still see the error message as following: java:31: error: cannot find symbol
     String SerialNumber = Build.getSerial();
                                ^
  symbol:   method getSerial()
  location: class Build
1 error
:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Comment: Finally, I don't know how but despite i's been deprecated with API 2.6, Build.SERIAL functions in my situation.

Comment: @SoundOfThunder Yes, you are right. Check my updated answer as well.

Answer (score 4):

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O && PermissionsUtility.checkPermission
(PermissionsUtility.PHONE_STATE_PERMISSION, getActivity())) {
                    SerialNumber = Build.getSerial();

            } else {
            SerialNumber = Build.SERIAL;
        }
```

The best way is to surround it with permission check before calling Build.getSerial() even though you have already asked permission from the user.
This is the clean way to do. This will not crash and works smoothly.
Make sure you have added the permission in the manifest file.
Here PermissionsUtility is the utility class to check permission which returns
returns

```
        public static final String PHONE_STATE_PERMISSION = 
Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE;

public static boolean checkPermission(String permission, Activity activity) {
    return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, permission) == 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}
```

This simply checks if your app has the permission or not. In Permission pass PHONE_STATE_PERMISSION.

Comment: Just pass `Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE` instead of declaring redundant string constant.

Comment: This is failing my lint for some reason: `Error: Missing permissions required by Build.getSerial: android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE [MissingPermission]
                  return Build.getSerial();` I have it wrapped in the same conditional to check for Android OS and permission. Any idea how to appease the Linter?

Answer (score 1):

In Android 9, Build.SERIAL is always set to "UNKNOWN" to protect users' privacy.

If your app needs to access a device's hardware serial number, you should instead request the READ_PHONE_STATE permission, then call getSerial().

Build.getSerial() method can be used from API26 and requires READ_PHONE_STATE.

To get more information, please refer to following link:https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28